# Error al actualizar una tabla con ciclo for desde angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Estoy realizando la siguiente consulta que es para buscar los ID's para actualizar una columna de cada registro encontrado:

```
this.PTService.BuscarOTAbiertas().subscribe(r => {
this.longitudDatos = r;
}
```

Para obtener en forma de array lo que hago es lo siguiente:

```
for (let i in this.longitudDatos) {
    this.datosOT.push(this.longitudDatos[i]['ot']);
  }
```

Lo cual le estoy agregando con push, al imprimirlo en consola me aparece lo siguiente:

```
['1           ', '2           ']
```

entonces para actualizar la base de datos , hago esto

```
if (this.datosOT.length > 0) {
 for (let i = 1; i <= this.datosOT.length; i++) {
 this.PTService.ActualizarOTAbiertas(this.datosOT[i]).subscribe(r => { });
}
```

Pero solo me actualiza el primer registro, al imprimir en consola

> console.log('OT ' + this.datosOT[i])

cada vez que accede a cada valor me aparece lo siguiente:

```
OT 2
OT undefined
```

y no se como o porque sucede eso

Comment: Los arrays en Javascript empiezan en 0, no en 1. Prueba a poner `let i=0` en el bucle

Comment: Lo hice también pero solo me actualiza el primero

Comment: @EnriquedeJesusJuarezCruz muestra el codigo de ese servicio: this.PTService.BuscarOTAbiertas()... sospecho que se soluciona ahí con la implementacion de Rxjs o alguna cosa asincrona.